# How to check if time period is fully covered by smaller periods in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, validation

Having tables like the following:

```
create table originalPeriods (
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Start] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [End] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Flag1] INT NOT NULL,
    [Flag2] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UC_UniueFlags UNIQUE (Flag1,Flag2)
)
go

create table convertedPeriods(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Start] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [End] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Flag1] INT NOT NULL,
    [Flag2] INT NOT NULL
)
go
```

I want to check whether every period from the first table is represented by a set of periods from the second table with matching Flags.

I want converted periods (from the second table) to fill the whole original period (from the first period) with no empty spaces, no overlapping and no extensions! Converted periods should fit the original period exactly.

The perfect outcome would be a list of original periods Id with the flag of whether it is well covered by converted periods.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Yep, you need to provide some samples, and what they look like and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just because you offered a bounty doesn't mean you can get away with not showing what you've tried in an attempt to solve the problem yourself. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ - use this to setup some data. Then link it. And tabulate actual data and expected results in your question. (or Google SQL Playground. There are alternatives too).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @RicoW: you should review the comments that have been posted and try to improve your question. Your bounty is at risk of being wasted if you don't provide the required, additional information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers but I'm afraid their effectiveness was not sufficient.

For anyone haveing a similar problem in the future - I ended applying two checks:

First would check if for each original period there is:

1. period starting at the same time
2. period ending at the same time
3. each converted (apart from the ending one as in 2.) period has a following period.

   SELECT
       op.Id
   ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM convertedPeriods ps WHERE op.Start=ps.Start AND op.Flag1=cp.Flag1 AND op.Flag2=cp.Flag2)
   ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM convertedPeriods ps WHERE op.End=ps.End AND op.Flag1=cp.Flag1 AND op.Flag2=cp.Flag2)
   ,(SELECT COUNT(cp.Id) FROM convertedPeriods cp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM convertedPeriods cp2 WHERE cp2.Start=cp.End) AND cp.End <> op.End)
   FROM
       originalPeriods op

While there can be false positives with this method, there are not false negatives - meaning every correct period representations must pass this test.

Second check was simply to generate random number of timestamps and compare whether they are covered in originals the same as in converted.

Those methods have proven themself to be succesful check for period's coverage comparement against huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, let me know if it works:

```
select
    op.Id
    ,[Flag: Converted Period matches Original Period] = case when cp.Id is not null then 'Found' else 'Not Found' end

from originalPeriods as op
left join convertedPeriods as cp on cp.[Start] = op.[Start] and cp.[End] = op.[End]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are lookin for something like this

```
with RECURSIVE periodsNet as (
    select o.id, o.dtstart, o.dtend,
    c.dtend as netPoint, 
    exists(select * from convertedPeriods c2
     where (c2.dtstart > c.dtstart and c2.dtstart < c.dtend)
     or (c2.dtend > c.dtstart and c2.dtend < c.dtend)
    ) as hasOverlap
    from originalPeriods o
    inner join convertedPeriods c
    on o.dtstart = c.dtstart    
    union all 
    select o.id, o.dtstart as ostart, o.dtend as oend,
    c.dtend as netPoint, 
    exists(select * from convertedPeriods c2
     where (c2.dtstart > c.dtstart and c2.dtstart < c.dtend)
     or (c2.dtend > c.dtstart and c2.dtend < c.dtend)
    ) as hasOverlap
    from periodsNet o
    inner join convertedPeriods c
    on o.netPoint = c.dtstart
),
periodsFilled as (
    select id, dtstart, dtend,
    case when dtend = max(netPoint) then true else false end filled
    from periodsNet
    group by id, dtstart, dtend
)
select *,
exists(select * from periodsNet n where n.id = p.id and n.hasOverlap) as hasOverlap
from periodsFilled p
```

see fiddle> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpezmztvj7uFg1PvixaBsh/0

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to check if periods is coverd is this one from ask Tom:
from [enter link description here][1]

```
select * from (
  select nmi, 
    max(invoice_end_date) over(
      partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date
    ) + 1 start_gap,
    lead(invoice_start_date) over(
      partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date
    ) - 1 end_gap
  from icr_tmp
)
where start_gap <= end_gap;
```

it works as a charm
[1]: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=sql-to-find-gaps-in-date-ranges